# NextJS '/' to index.js loads nothing

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

I'm new to Next.js I'm having a problem where `http://localhost:3000` doesn't work when using client side routing, but loads when I use refresh.

My `Header.js` file that shows the navigation

```
import Link from 'next/link'
const Header = () => (
    <div>
        <Link href='/'>
          <a style={linkStyle}>Home</a>
        </Link>

        <Link href='/about'>
          <a style={linkStyle}>About</a>
        </Link>

        <Link href='/listing'>
            <a style={linkStyle}>Search</a>
        </Link>

    </div>
)

export default Header
```

**then on `server.js` I have almost the default codes from Next.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express()

  server.get('/listing/:id', (req,res) => {
    const actualPage = '/listing'
    const queryParams = {
      id: req.params.id
    }
    app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams)

  })

  server.get('*', (req,res) => {
    return handle(req, res)
  })

  server.listen(3000, (err) => {
    if (err)
      throw err
    console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000')
  })
}).catch((ex) => {
  console.error(ex.stack)
  process.exit(1)
})
```

my `/about` and `/listing` page works and if I use `/nonexistance-url` it will `return 404`. However, I cannot client side link to `/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Apparently this is a bug with next-css**

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
module.exports = withCSS({/* my next config */})
```

These 2 Threads are talking about this and it's apparently difficult to fix, in case someone chance upon this same error.

https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/5291

https://spectrum.chat/thread/2183fc55-236d-42cb-92b9-3ab10acc6303

Temporary Solution suggested by the above post that works for me.

> Create a empty css file and import it in your _app.js